# Faster way to write lots of small files without the filesystem cache?

Tags: c#, file, io, filesystems

I have an app that needs to write a lot of files (10s of thousands) that are all fairly small in size (4KB to 64KB generally).  They need to be written in a manner that is durable, i.e. without the filesystem cache.  Is there a faster way you know of other than the way I'm doing it below?  ANTS is saying that this is the bottleneck in my code (and yes I understand disk will almost always be the bottleneck).  It's sad seeing such low throughput on an SSD, but I understand since the files are small.  These files will never be appended.

```
    using (var fs = new FileStream(
        filename, 
        System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, 
        FileAccess.Write, 
        FileShare.None, 
        0x1000, 
        FileOptions.WriteThrough))
    {
        fs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
```

Comment: The entire purpose of the filesystem cache is to speed writing by buffering file I/O. You're asking *how can I write faster while intentionally drastically slowing things down by not using the cache the OS provides to write faster?*, which makes absolutely no sense. It seems like one of those "*Doctor, it hurts when I do this.* *So stop doing that.*" type situations.

Comment: I understand, I'm asking if there is a way to do it faster in cases where I have to write-through.